# Android Studio: How to create an empty String Array?

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create a series of Strings:

```
String a="";
String b="";
String c="";
String d="";
String e="";
```

And I would like to create a String Array to put these Strings into it, and I've tried to write like this:

```
String[] abcde = {"a","b","c","d","e"}
```

but it's not my desire as i just want the Strings to be empty...
Sorry i know it seems just a simple question to you, but i'm a new learner, looking forward to hearing your help. Thanks!

Comment: String[] abcde = {a,b,c,d,e} use this.

Comment: @chunyuen2 Did you get help from any answer?

Comment: @santoshkumar Thanks a lot, i got it!

Comment: @MilapTank Yes, Thanks!

Comment: Accept helped answer so other can also get help from your contribution :)

Comment: @MilapTank yup, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly simple task, you will simply want to use:

```
String[] abcde = {a, b, c, d, e}
```

You are wrapping your initial variables with "", this refers to a being "a" which is now a string with the character a.

I hope that will help you address your problem and here is a link for further help with strings.
[Strings Java](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-string-array-reference-java-5-for-loop-syntax)

Answer (score 1):

just remove quotes

`String[] abcde = {a, b, c , d , e };`

Answer (score 1):

Well the good news is that this question isn't specific to Android or Android Studio, so you can actually broaden your search. The even better news is that you don't have to because I'm going to tell you right here.

What your code does is add 5 unnamed strings with contents "a", "b", "c", "d, and "e", rather than adding the references to the string objects that you've created. So just do this

```
    String a = "";
    String b = "";
    String c = "";
    String[] butts = {a, b, c};
```

and you will add the references.

Answer (score 1):

I am  still confusing your Question but whatever I got it for this  `i just want the Strings to be empty` so you can try this way

```
 String[] labels = new String[length];
 Arrays.fill(labels, "");
```

If I am wrong let me know #SOReadyToHelp :)

Comment: I've achieved that!
First declared:

`String a="";
String b="";
String c="";
String d="";
String e="";`

Then create a String Array to put the declared Strings inside:

`String[] abcde = {"a","b","c","d","e"}`


Thanks!